# How can I find the element in qualtrics online survey with python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I am working on a marketing project which I have to collect 300+ responses using Qualtrics survey. However, I am not able to get that many results.

So, I am trying to autofill the surveys with selenium and python. But I encountered a problem that I cannot find the element.

FYI: the link of the survey: https://hkbuhk.ca1.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_cuvrHqLdEhcwTEV

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
driver.get('https://hkbuhk.ca1.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_cuvrHqLdEhcwTEV')

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id="QR~QID2~1"]").click()
```

It returns an error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate 
element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="QR~QID2~1"]"}
```

May I know how to solve this? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below solution, Its a synnchronization issue and you can avoid it using Webdriver wait.

```
driver.get("https://hkbuhk.ca1.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_cuvrHqLdEhcwTEV")
driver.maximize_window()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='QR~QID2~1']"))).click()
```

**Note :** please add below imports to your solution

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

Comment: would you kind enough to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) answer and hit upvote button from your end.

Comment: I would love to upvote it but my reputation is not high enough to do so.
"Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."